# What is the difference between '0.0.0.0/1' and 'default'?

Tags: ip, routing, openvpn, route, tunneling

Crew, please take a look at the routing table below. Incoming ping requests from 172.17.4.x are accepted on dev ens160 and answered via dev tun0.

- What is the difference between '0.0.0.0/1' and 'default'?
- What changes are needed to have trafic from 172.17.4.x answered via ens160?

Host: 172.31.4.225
Lan: 172.31.4.0/24
GW: 172.31.4.1
tun0: tunnel to access internet (openvpn)
ens160: vm network interface
Remote client: 172.17.4.x

```
# ip route
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.z.0.1 dev tun0
default via 172.31.4.1 dev ens160 proto dhcp src 172.31.4.225 metric 100
10.z.0.0/16 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.z.0.6
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.23.0.1 dev tun0
172.16.0.0/16 via 172.31.4.1 dev ens160
172.31.4.0/24 dev ens160 proto kernel scope link src 172.31.4.225
172.31.4.1 dev ens160 proto dhcp scope link src 172.31.4.225 metric 100
u.w.x.y via 172.31.4.1 dev ens160
192.168.19.0/24 dev br-<snip> proto kernel scope link src 192.168.19.1
192.168.68.0/24 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.68.1 linkdown
```

Answer (score 7):

> ```
> 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.z.0.1 dev tun0
> 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.z.0.1 dev tun0
> ```

Those two rules, together span the whole of `0.0.0.0/0` (the first one IP addresses from 0.0.0.0 to 127.255.255.255 and the second IP address from 128.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255) and have precedence over the:

> ```
> default via 172.31.4.1 dev ens160 proto dhcp src 172.31.4.225 metric 100
> ```

rule (`default` being `0.0.0.0/0`) as they have a narrower scope.

Those are added by `openvpn` at least when you use `--redirect-gateway def1`.

From the man page:

> **def1**   Use this flag to override the default gateway by using 0.0.0.0/1 and 128.0.0.0/1 rather than 0.0.0.0/0. This has the benefit of overriding but not wiping out the original default gateway.

Comment: Ah that makes more sense. I couldn't figure any reason why someone would use `/1` routing rules.

Comment: Thank you Stéphane. This system has indeed openvpn installed. My intention is to use this tunnel for all non-local traffic. Can this be achieved by a openvpn (client)-setting? Or do I have to manipulate the routing table manually? (of by script to make it persistent?)

Comment: Is there any rationale besides that? Because you can have multiple default routes with different metrics (in fact, NetworkManager does exactly that by default). I don't see the point of that kludge.

Comment: @UncleBilly The rationale: this is for when the default route has no metric defined (here it has a `metric 100` so a default route using for example `metric 50` could override it): that means metric 0 and no other default route can override it, except a narrower route. So using two /1 routes always trumps over a /0 route even if its metric can't be overriden. OpenVPN can even do this with 4 /2 routes (0.0.0.0/2 + 64.0.0.0/2 + 128.0.0.0/2 + 192.0.0.0/2) to override these two /1 routes using "def2".

Comment: @UncleBilly this works on any OS. There are other specialized ways to override it. Eg (if I understood correctly): [WireGuard](https://www.wireguard.com/netns/#improved-rule-based-routing) suggests using ip rule with `suppress_prefixlength` to bypass only the default route, but it's not so generic.

Comment: @A.B Thanks. Now I feel like I could override OpenVPN's super-default route with my own by adding 4 /2s routes ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The important thing to notice is `/1` means the first [bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit) in the ip address must be `0`.  IP addresses with the first bit set to `1` will not match.  The default rule will match all IP addresses if no other rule does.  In practice this means `0.0.0.0/1` will only match IP addresses `0.0.0.0` to `127.x.x.x` ... actually it only matches `0.0.0.0` to `126.x.x.x` because `127.x.x.x` are local loopback and never routed.  The default rule is effectively `0.0.0.0/0` so that it matches all IP addresses.

Note that routing table also has a rule `128.0.0.0/1`.  All IPv4 addresses will match either `0.0.0.0/1` or `128.0.0.0/1` so the default rule will never be used.

> What changes are needed to have traffic from 172.17.4.x answered via ens160?

Add another rule for `172.17.4.0/24` routing through `ens160` to `172.31.4.1`.  This *should* be acceptable since this routing table already believes `172.31.4.1` is an acceptable default gateway.  We get `/24` because the first 3 bytes (3 times 8 bits) must match the first three bytes in `172.31.4.0` (`172` `31` `4`) and we don't care about the 4th `x`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. You assumed ```172.17.4.0/24``` is a ```/24``` network. This is not correct. It's a ```/16```. This might be an omission in my post. Sorry. You suggest adding a new route. I've tried this by adding ```172.16.0.0/16 via 172.31.4.1 dev ens160```.  This should have the same effect yes? In my experience it does not. I'll continue in Stéphane Chazelas' answer.

Comment: @sandmouse I didn't assume anything, that's what you wrote. `172.17.4.x` is a `/24` network, that's what the `x` means. The `/16` network is `172.17.x.x`.  A `/16` may not have the same effect as `/24` if there are overlapping rules.  The higher number wins, so overlapping networks with smaller subnets (higher number) override larger networks (smaller number).

Comment: @sandmouse note the difference between `172.16.0.0/16` and `172.17.0.0/16`.  That may be why it didn't work.